# I want to style every odd p element excluding hidden p element

Tags: css

I am having below HTML content.

```css
p.a {
  display: none;
}

p:not(.a):nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>text1</p>
<p class="a">text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p class="a">text4</p>
<p>text5</p>
<p>text6</p>
<p>text7</p>
<p>text8</p>
```

My expectation is that it should exclude the hidden elements while applying the background color, and the output should be as below:

[image]

Note: I cannot make any change in the HTML file.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: actually `p:not(.a):nth-of-type(odd)` means _match all odd paragraphs if they have not the class .a_

Comment: @fcalderan what is the solution??